# Kivy stop Video and show photo

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a kivy framework (v1.10). I'm trying to create a simple photo booth software that runs a video loop and stops the video when someone clicks on the screen. After that the camera takes a picture and the program displays it on the monitor together with two buttons yes or no. they will allow you to repeat the photo. I am developing this application for Raspberry PI. My question is how do I stop the video and make something else.

ok, so if I want to add another movie between the first movie and the buttons, do I have to add a new screen or maybe change the video source in this funtion self.bind (on_touch_down = self.on_stop)? I would like to add a video with a countdown time and let him release the camera by taking pictures. then display this photo once with the buttons: repeat and continue.

```html
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import Video
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout



class Player(Video):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(Player,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './START.mp4'
        self.state='play'
        self.options={'eos': 'loop'}
        self.bind(on_touch_down = self.on_stop)
        self.get_set_current_video_state = self.get_set_current_video_state()

    def check(self):
        Logger.info("film position:" + str(self.position))

    def on_stop(self,  *args):
        print ('I have been clicked')
        Player.state='stop'
        #App.get_running_app().stop()
        #self.get_set_current_video_state = ('pause')
        return MyWindowApp().run()


class VideoPlayerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Player()

class MyWindowApp(App):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindowApp, self).__init__()


        self.btn = Button(text='Push Me!')
        self.lbl = Label(text='Read Me!')
```

Comment: Consider `VideoPlayer.state = 'stop'` as described in [Video Player](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.videoplayer.html#kivy.uix.videoplayer.VideoPlayer.state).

Comment: this command closed my app, but how i can stop the video and run other activity. eg menu with photo background with two buttons yes or no.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say it will close the app. Try `pause` instead of `stop`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping a kivy video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601191/stopping-a-kivy-video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use two `Apps`, just use two `Screens`. Here is a modification of your code using `Screens`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button



class Player(Video):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(Player,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = './START.mp4'
        self.state='play'
        self.options={'eos': 'loop'}
        self.bind(on_touch_down = self.on_stop)

    def check(self):
        Logger.info("film position:" + str(self.position))

    def on_stop(self,  *args):
        print ('I have been clicked')
        self.state='stop'  # stop the video
        sm.current = 'WindowApp'  # switch to the other Screen


class MyWindowApp(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindowApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        self.btn = Button(text='Push Me!', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.75}, size_hint=(0.2, 0.2))
        self.lbl = Label(text='Read Me!', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.25})

        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.add_widget(self.lbl)

sm = ScreenManager()
screen1 = Screen(name='video')
screen1.add_widget(Player())
sm.add_widget(screen1)
screen2 = MyWindowApp(name='WindowApp')
sm.add_widget(screen2)

class VideoPlayerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


VideoPlayerApp().run()
```

I corrected your import to `from kivy.uix.video import Video`

Comment: ok, so if I want to add another movie between the first and the buttons, do I have to add a new screen or maybe change the video source in this funtion self.bind (on_touch_down = self.on_stop)? I would like to add a video with a countdown and let him release the camere by taking pictures. then display this photo once with the buttons: repeat and continue.